# Post ID displayed instead of title

Tags: widgets, blog

I added the "recent post" widget on my blog but instead of blog titles it displays some random numbers:

Take a look [here](https://gopersonal.com.au/2017/07/24/why-video-personalisation-is-the-future-of-communication/).

I have given titles to these blog so I don't understand where these numbers are coming from. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Hi. Those are not random numbers. Those are post IDs. Add `/?p=503` to your domain and you will be redirected to the post that has the 503 as its title (for example, `http://my-site.com/?p=503`). And as for the reason, it's unknown to me. Unfortunately questions about third party plugins are off-topic here, and must be asked on their representative support forums.

Comment: thank you for your comment. This is not a plugin though, this is a widget that is offered by wordpress.

Comment: My apologies, now that's weird. Have you tried using the default `twentyseven` theme and see if the problem persists?

Comment: I feel as if this is not a normal WordPress widget but whatever page builder you have in place. If I were to make a guess it's Site Origin. You're better off taking this issue to them

Comment: that makes sense. My apologies. Didn't realise that was a plugin.

Comment: I have the same widget in a fresh installation. Are you sure "recent posts" is not a part of WP? :) @Howdy_McGee